# SQL conversion failed when converting the varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, nvarchar

OK just joined stackoverflow today and I am very new to scripting, specially SQL 
I am trying to run below to get a invoice num

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   [Database].[dbo].[Table]
WHERE
    [EPSINO] = 915561
    AND [EPYEA4] = 2017
    AND [EPSPYN] = EPSPYN
    AND [EPCONO] = 100
    AND [EPDIVI] = 400
GO
```

But I'm getting an error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'R8463                   ' to data type int.

Understand I need a convert line in there somewhere but not sure where

PLEASE HELP

Thanks

Comment: Its Int & Char eg. "RON002"

Comment: Please edit your question and post the data types of each column in use. Then we can suggest a solution without guessing (and confusing you)

Comment: Updated Question. Let me know if missing anything..

Answer (score 2):

Look at the datatypes defined on your columns.  nvarchar columns need to be wrapped in single quotes.  For example, EPSPYN is most likely an nvarchar column.  I can't tell if the remaining columns are int or nvarchar.  You need to look at your table definition and wrap in quotes appropriately.

```
select * 
from[Database].[dbo].[Table]
where [EPSINO] = 915561
      and [EPYEA4] = 2017
      and [EPSPYN] = 'EPSPYN'
      and [EPCONO] = 100
      and [EPDIVI] = 400
 GO
```

Comment: Thanks @LAS I added quotes and query worked fine but came blank result which i need to find out if right or wrong

Answer (score 1):

When you have a column of type char, you have to compare its value within single quotes. So if column `EPSPYN` was of type char, ensure that the value against it is written within single quote.

```
Select * From[Database].[dbo].[Table]
WHERE
    [EPSINO] = 915561
 and [EPYEA4] = 2017
 and [EPSPYN] = 'EPSPYN' -- See this.
 and [EPCONO] = 100
 and [EPDIVI] = 400
GO
```

Comment: Thanks @Nisarg Shah  no error with quotes on EPSPYN but no result have to find if it suppose to be blank

Comment: That means there's nothing in the data that matches 'EPSPYN' exactly. You might want to use a like query if you are comparing only a part of string: `[EPSPYN] LIKE '%E%'`

Answer (score 0):

First find out the datatypes of that table, then build the WHERE clause. like VARCHAR, NVARCHAR and DATE Type enclose the Search text with Single Quotes.
Use Below command for the list of columns and its datatypes and build your Query.

```
SP_HELP [Database].[dbo].[Table]
```